# R statistics console in QT

Tags: r, qt4

I am planning to link a Qt project against R to provide some statistical funcionality. I thought it might be quite cute to add some generality to the project by having an R console as a Qt widget within the tab to allow me to do analyses that I haven't thought of in the design stage later on. I was wondering whether it is something that might be accomplished fairly easily?

In particular I'm stuck on how I would access the RTerm from QT? Has anyone else attempted something similar or can give some hints on where to start?

Comment: Is your question "can I easily create an R GUI frontend in Qt even though I'm quite new to Qt and not willing to devote a huge amount of time to this task?".  The answer is obviously no.

Comment: If you are willing to relax some of the conditions (it being easy, not devoting much time, etc.) you might stand a chance.

Comment: Also, as it stands, this question is fuzzy enough to warrant closing.  I suggest you rephrase as "how do I call Rterm from a Qt widget?", or something similarly concrete.

Comment: The first comment is probably a little glib, I appreciate that its not a trivial task however I go about it. I have made a some progress with a simple terminal. Although I take the point that I does read more like a coffee break discussion. I shall edit.

Comment: Apologies for glibness; no offense intended.  And for the record, I think it sounds like a cool project.

Comment: You might want to have a look at [RInside](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rinside.html) and [Rcpp](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp.html).

Comment: @Bowler: The question is looking much better.  Have an upvote.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One of the examples for [**RInside**](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rinside.html) does something pretty close---in around 200 lines most of which deal with the other GUI aspects, it wraps R functionality inside a [**Qt**](http://www.qt-project.org) application.

The example implements a GUI density slider, and the edit box allows you to write an almost arbitrary R expression, or rather the parts that are then passed into an evaluation to generate random number:  `rnorm(50)`, or for a mixture `c(rnorm(50), rt(50))` etc.  You could possibly build on top of that.

See this [blog post](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/blog/2011/03/25/) for more.

Comment: This seems very promising. I've had a look an I image this would work with the little console widget I now have. I'll have a go when I get a chance and accept the answer.

Comment: I'm still someway from my R-terminal widget but I think I have all I need other than time.

Answer (score 4):

Check out Carson Farmer's work on manageR:

http://www.ftools.ca/manageR/

this is a plugin for Quantum GIS (mapping package) that interfaces it to R, giving you exactly what you want - an R console wrapped in a Qt4 body - as well as data transfer between Qgis and R. It handles plots as well.

I've tried to encourage Carson to produce a standalone R Gui project from this code, but he's a busy guy. Aren't we all?

Answer (score 3):

RStudio is largely written using QT, you should be able to have a look at their code and build something similar into your Qt based application:

https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio

Comment: "Something being written in X" does not generally equal "being able to factor out use of X".

Comment: No but I said "should be able to" not "will be able to". But the example on your blog is considerably better than shifting through RStudio source code.